# positive iterator design given an integer iterator

Tags: algorithm, iterator

> given an IntegerIterator （which implements hasNext, next, remove),
>   implement a PositiveIterator that has hasNext, next, remove

Can anyone give some ideas for this problem? It's not a homework!

For example:

```
int[] a = new int[]{1,-2,-3,4,5,-6,7,-8,9};
IntegerIterator it = new IntegerIterator(a);
PositiveIterator iter = new PositiveIterator(it);
Console.WriteLine(iter.HasNext()); //true
Console.WriteLine(iter.HasNext()); //true
Console.WriteLine(iter.HasNext()); //true
Console.WriteLine(iter.Next()); //1
Console.WriteLine(iter.Next()); //4
Console.WriteLine(iter.Next()); //5
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`PositiveIterator.Next` shouldn't be a problem. Just call `Iterator.Next` until the value is positive. `PositiveIterator.Remove` just needs a call to `Iterator.Remove`. `PositiveIterator.HasNext` is the reason why the code will be a bit ugly, since the given methods only allow unidirectional iteration.

```
class PositiveIterator:
    int next = -1 //holds the next value to return
    IntegerIterator iter //the integeriterator wrapped by this object

    PositiveIterator(IntegerIterator it)
        iter = it

        //search for the first positive value for next
        while iter.HasNext() AND ((next = iter.Next()) < 1)
            NOOP

    HasNext()
        return next != -1

    Next()
        //the current value to return
        int tmp = next

        //search for the next positive value
        while iter.HasNext() AND ((next = iter.Next()) < 1)
            NOOP

        if NOT iter.HasNext()
            next = -1 //no next positive value available

        return tmp

     Remove()
         if next == -1
             return

         iter.Remove()

         //update the next value
         next = Next()
```

Basically `PositiveInteger` needs to predict the value for the value that will be returned next.

Answer (score 0):

This is pretty straight forward - override the constructor, `HashNext()` and `Next()` methods, such you will always have "in hand" the next positive value, while skipping all negative values.

Pseudo code:

```
class PositiveIterator:
    private int next = -1;
    private final Integer i;
    PositiveIterator(Itertor i):
          while (i.HashNext() && (next = i.Next()) <= 0) ;
          //at this point next holds the next positive element, if such exists
          this.i = i;
    boolean HasNext():
         return (next > 0)
    int Next():
         int tempVal = -1;
         while (i.HashNext() && (tempVal = i.Next()) <= 0) ;
         int res = next;
         next = tempVal;
         return next;
```

Note that at any point, in any method - `next > 0` if and only if there is some positive element left in the array, and it will hold the next element you need t produce.